# How to set width of div to another div's width?

Tags: javascript, html, css, width

I'm trying to set, with javascript, the width of one `div` to the width of another.  In my case, the second `div` was cloned from the first.

The issue I'm running into is related to padding, and how style.width is defined differently from clientWidth/offsetWidth/scrollWidth.  In my example below, I have two `div`s defined the same except with different widths.  When the button is pressed, I'm trying to set the width of the smaller one to the bigger one - but the outcome is that it gets the width of the bigger one PLUS the padding (an extra 20px).

Is there a way to change the line:

```
two.style.width = one.clientWidth + 'px';
```

to make the two `div`s equal in width?

```js
function setWidth() {
  var one = document.getElementById("one");
  var two = document.getElementById("two");
  two.style.width = one.clientWidth + 'px';
}
```

```css
.outer {
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
  } 
.inner {
  background: green;
  height: 10px;
  } 

#one {
  width: 100px; 
}
#two {
  width:50px;
    }
```

```html
<div id=one class=outer><div class=inner></div></div>
<br>
<div id=two class=outer><div class=inner></div></div>
<button onclick="setWidth()">SET WIDTH</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use getComputedStyle:

```
function setWidth() {
  var one = document.getElementById("one");
  var two = document.getElementById("two");
  style = window.getComputedStyle(one);
  wdt = style.getPropertyValue('width');
  two.style.width = wdt;
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g0fejyuk/)

Comment: This one works, and does not require I have to fiddle with the padding.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You should make use of .offsetWidth. They belong to the element, not .style.

```
function setWidth() {
    var w=document.getElementById('one').offsetWidth
    document.getElementById('two').setAttribute("style","width:"+w+"px");
}
```

Comment: That still doesnt take into account padding.  See it in this JS Fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/igor_9000/6Lja4ytn/

Comment: We can get padding value and subtract it from w. window.getComputedStyle(one, null).getPropertyValue('padding-left'). where one is reference to element with Id one.

Answer (score 0):

The width isn't taking into account the padding.  You'll still need to subtract it.  Something like this should work:

```
function setWidth() {
  var one = document.getElementById("one");
  var two = document.getElementById("two");

  two.style.width = one.offsetWidth  + 'px';

  //update the width again, subtracting the difference between the first div and the second (which includes padding)
  two.style.width = (two.offsetWidth-((two.offsetWidth - one.offsetWidth)*2))  + 'px';
}
```

You can see it working here: https://jsfiddle.net/igor_9000/55d1pfak/1/

For what its worth, jQuery handles this a little easier and gets the elements width including padding/borders.  That may be another option for you.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You need to take `one`'s padding into consideration.

```
function setWidth() {
  var one = document.getElementById("one");
  var two = document.getElementById("two");
  var leftPadding = window.getComputedStyle(one, null).getPropertyValue('padding-left');
  var width = window.getComputedStyle(one, null).getPropertyValue('width');

  two.style.width = width;
  two.style.padding = leftPadding;
}
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9kcp3rbz/).

Answer (score 0):

My code will find the largest width for all elements using class 'js-equal-width' and it will set all of them to the same width.

```
$(function() {
    const extraWidth = 50
    var maxWidth = 0
    $('.js-equal-width').each(function() {
        maxWidth = maxWidth > $(this).width() ? maxWidth : $(this).width()
    })

    $('.js-equal-width').each(function() {
        $(this).width(maxWidth + extraWidth)
    })
})
```

You can do it by using 'js-equal-width'

```
<div style="width: 300px;">
     <span class="js-equal-width">Midterm Examination</span>
     <span class="js-equal-width">Final Examination</span>
</div>
```